# Mailto tag puts text into the "To" field of email instead of subject on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, android

When I use my mobile applications mailto tag on my desktop everything works great but when I access my app on my 2.3 android phone the body of my email gets crammed into the "To" field. Is there any issues with mobile browsers and the mailto tag? Am I setting up the email incorrectly? I have made sure the email message cannot exeed 1,000 characters fully escaped, I cant think of anything else that would be causing this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
document.location.href = "mailto:&body=" + escape(myMessage.replace(/[^\u0000-\u007F]/, ""))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like:

```
document.location.href = "mailto:?body=" + escape(myMessage.replace(/[^\u0000-\u007F]/, ""))
```

note the question mark.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the mailto tag is doing exactly what it should and putting it in the "To" Field.. There is a tag to specify what goes to the subject line.. While I do not know the syntax im sure as simple google search would turn up the correct usage for you..

Answer (score 0):

You may optionally specify the recipient of the message first.

`mailto:recepient@gmail.com`

Next, the first parameter must be prepended by a `?`:

`mailto:recepient@gmail.com?body=`

Any further parameters (like to or subject) must be prepended by an `&`:

`mailto:recepient@gmail.com?body=yourbody&subject=example`

The `mailto:` must also be URL encoded, which I'm assuming you're doing in your `escape()` function.

More info at [About.com](http://email.about.com/od/mailtoemaillinks/a/mailto_elements.htm)